# How we get Style with appropriate with class name

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, iphone

I want to replace  with their style defined earlier and soon for all class. I am newer in iOS. it is dynamic HTML. which render in any format . I want to replace with appropriate style `<p class="p1"><span class="s1">` Sent

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
    <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 15.0px 'Helvetica Neue'}
    span.s1 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-size: 15.00px; text-decoration: underline}
    span.s2 {font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic'; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 15.00px; text-decoration: underline}
    span.s3 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00px}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Sent</span><span class="s2"> from </span><span class="s3">Zone</span><span class="s2"> Mail for </span><span class="s1">iOS</span></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the style by either overriding the style rule or simply reusing the same

1) Overriding the style rule

```
span.s1 {/*some css rules*/}
```

Then at some later point in the code file

```
span.s1 {/*some different css rules*/}
```

s1 class will now have the latest rules

2) Reusing the CSS rule by a different name

```
span.s1, span.s2, s3 {/* CSS rules */}
```

All elements having the classes as per above will have the same CSS effect.

Hope it helps!